# Meteor: reactive helper using Tracker.Dependency

Tags: meteor, helper

I have a helper

```
Template.home.helpers({
  songId: function(){
    return SongManager.getSongId();
  },
});
```

that uses the getSongId method from the SongManager

```
SongManager = {
  init: function(songId){
    this.dep = new Tracker.Dependency;
  },
  getSongId: function(){
    this.dep.depend();
    return this.songId;
  },
  setSongId: function(arg){
    this.songId = arg;
    this.dep.changed();
  },
}
```

But it doesn't cause the template to update reactively when setSongId is called. Am I doing anything wrong? If I use Session.get and Session.set, then everything works properly.

```
SongManager = {
  init: function(songId){
  },
  getSongId: function(){
    return Session.get('songId');
  },
  setSongId: function(arg){
    Session.set('songId', arg);
  },
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it but I'm quite surprised but the results: Placing inside `Meteor.startup()` doesn't work. I need to investigate why, there's is something about Blaze that I don't know yet.

Check the repo I created for this: https://github.com/mariorodriguespt/stack-song-manager

Comment: Sorry, I didn't show the init code because I put it in Meteor.startup. I actually don't want to use Session at all, I am just adding it there because my original code without Session is not working (see my edit).

Comment: Interesting. Somehow, this also works: SongManager = {dep: new Tracker.Dependency, init: ...}

Comment: It works because `this` in the `init` method is a reference to the `SongManager` object.